# Why is my RegExp ignoring start and end of strings?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I made this helper function to find single words, that are not part of bigger expressions
it works fine on any word that is NOT first or last in a sentence, why is that?
is there a way to add `""` to regexp?

```
String.prototype.findWord = function(word) {

    var startsWith = /[\[\]\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_~()\s]/ ;
    var endsWith = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/ ;

    var wordIndex = this.indexOf(word);

    if (startsWith.test(this.charAt(wordIndex - 1)) &&
        endsWith.test(this.charAt(wordIndex + word.length))) {

        return wordIndex;
    }
    else {return -1;}
}
```

Also, any improvement suggestions for the function itself are welcome!

UPDATE: example: I want to find the word `able` in a string, I waht it to work in cases like `[able] able, #able1` etc.. but not in cases that it is part of another word like `disable, enable` etc

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you give us an example input sentence and desired output? I don't know what "part of a bigger expression" means.

Comment: @Andy Ray I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

A different version:

```
String.prototype.findWord = function(word) {
   return this.search(new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b"));
}
```

Your `if` will only evaluate to true if `endsWith` matches after the word. But the last word of a sentence ends with a full stop, which won't match your alphanumeric expression.

Comment: thanx, so how do I add those to the regexp?

Comment: @IlyaD, I suggest you use my method :)

Comment: it works great but I don't completely understand it, Looked up `\b` and it says "word boundary", so it automatically does what I was aiming for..? :)

Comment: @IlyaD, yep. Nice isn't it ? :)

Comment: Very much :) is the fist `\` before `\b` meant to say thet the `\b` is regexp and not a string?

Comment: @davin Good answer, simple and efficient. But the metacharacter `\b` doesn't consider underscores or ciphers as word boundaries, for example `"_able".search(/\bable/)` returns -1.

Comment: @Luc1245, it's easily extendible; just change `"\\b"` to `"[\\b_]"`. My main point was the basic idea, not edge cases, but you're right.

Comment: @davin Hmm, it's not so easy. Once in square brackets, `\b` no longer works the same way. Say, if I try `"a able".search(/[\b_]able/)`, it returns -1, and it's the same thing with "a.able", "a+able" and so on...

Comment: @Luc1245, still a little strange that `\b` doesn't work in character classes, but you can fix it with `\b[_]*` and add any characters you want to the character class. Worth pointing out that if you include those characters, you need to remove their length from the returned value, otherwise it counts from where the _'s begin, not the word searched for.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try *word boundary* -- `\b`?

There is also `\w` which match one word character (`[a-zA-Z_]`) -- this could help you too (depends on your *word* definition).

See [RegExp docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more details.

Comment: I need to find what is **before** the searched word, if someone searches for `able` i need to see that it is not starting with a letter and can be `disable`

Comment: `\w` matches digits, too: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `endsWith` regexp also matches the empty string, you just need to append `|^$` to it:

```
var endsWith = /[^A-Za-z0-9]|^$/ ;
```

Anyway, you can easily check if it is the beginning of the text with `if (wordIndex == 0)`, and if it is the end with `if (wordIndex + word.length == this.length)`.

It is also possible to eliminate this issue by operating on a copy of the input string, surrounded with non-alphanumerical characters. For example:

```
var s = "#" + this + "#"; 
var wordIndex = this.indexOf(word) - 1;
```

But I'm afraid there is another problems with your function:
it would never match "able" in a string like "disable able enable" since the call to `indexOf` would return 3, then `startsWith.test(wordIndex)` would return `false` and the function would exit with -1 without searching further.

So you could try:

```
String.prototype.findWord = function (word) {

   var startsWith = "[\\[\\]\\.,-\\/#!$%\\^&\*;:{}=\\-_~()\\s]";
   var endsWith =   "[^A-Za-z0-9]";

   var wordIndex = ("#"+this+"#").search(new RegExp(startsWith + word + endsWith)) - 1;

   if (wordIndex == -1) { return -1; }
   return wordIndex;
}
```